# Objective C Obfuscate Method and Function Parameters

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am dealing with some code, I got 2 Options:

Either: Use a Method

> [object doSomethingWithOffset:0x12345];

Or: Use a Function `doSomething(0x12345);`

Because I am dealing with Offsets, that no one actually should see, I need to obfuscate them. using `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` I can hide the NAMES of the methods/functions.

But when disassembling the Binary output file, you see something like this:

```
LDR     R2, =0xOFFSET
LDR     R3, =0xDATA
```

So the offset I put as a PARAMETER can be found.

Is there a convenient way to HIDE the parameters of a function / method call?

Thanks for helping.

Jack

Comment: You mean you want to not show what the data and offsets are in the code? You could calculate them, I suppose. But unless you jump through hoops to make the calculation itself difficult to follow, someone will figure out that `((((1 << 4)| 2) << 4) + 3) * 16 ...))` is the same as 12345 (assuming the compiler didn't do it in itself).

Comment: why dont you make your own algo to encrypt it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you think this is necessary; the normal way of "hiding" methods you don't want to be generally accessible is to make them class-private (in Objective-C this means not declaring prototypes in the interface and having the methods exist only in the implementation). Trying to hide or obfuscate method calls themselves will only make things harder for any future debuggers (which could include yourself; even if this is a personal project, don't think that you don't have to worry about future maintainability).

That being said, there probably are some LLVM IR transformations out there you could use to do some obfuscation, but I still wouldn't recommend it because it would likely result in decreased efficiency of your code as it would be harder for the compiler to optimize (or the compiler would just optimize out the obfuscation anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hide stuff from someone disassembling your code, you can't.  You *can* obfuscate things enough to make it confusing to the guy, but that's not real good security.

If you do choose to obfuscate, the best thing to do is to embed your method, with a bogus name, among a bunch of other similarly-named methods that do entirely useful & necessary yet boring things.

There's not really any good way to hide the data if "the guy" knows on what method calls it's being passed.  You can "construct" this secret value using a combo of operations, but that risks actually attracting attention, if it seems out of character for the app.

(But if I were going to try to hide such a computation I'd likely try to make it look like the computation of an offset in the GUI, and hide it among real such computations.  Maybe even stash parts of the value as offsets of a hidden label or some such.)